# Find time difference in minutes using a PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find the time difference between the last updated time and current time for a file. How do I extract TotalMinutes data from the output?

```
$Date = Get-Date
$Files = gci "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\command.txt"
ForEach ($File in $Files){
    $FileDate = $File.LastWriteTime
}
$DURATION=$Date-$FileDate
Echo $DURATION

Output is coming as below
Days              : 0
Hours             : 2
Minutes           : 21
Seconds           : 37
Milliseconds      : 311
Ticks             : 84973115857
TotalDays         : 0.0983485137233796
TotalHours        : 2.36036432936111
TotalMinutes      : 141.621859761667
TotalSeconds      : 8497.3115857
TotalMilliseconds : 8497311.5857
```

Comment: "batch-file" tag, but Powershell code?

Comment: `$DURATION.TotalMinutes`?

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for the answer, this is what i am looking for.

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 12):

You will not need a loop, after getting a single file:

```
$Files = gci "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\command.txt"
ForEach ($File in $Files){
    $FileDate = $File.LastWriteTime
}
```

In this case, `$Files` might as well be `$File`, making the loop completely redundant:

```
$File = gci "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\command.txt"
$FileDate = $File.LastWriteTime
```

In the exact same way you extracted `LastWriteTime`, you can get `TotalMinutes`:

```
$Date = Get-Date
$DURATION = $Date - $FileDate
$DURATION.TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$StartDate=(GET-DATE)
#wait a few seconds
$EndDate=(GET-DATE)
$diff = NEW-TIMESPAN -Start $StartDate -End $EndDate
Write-Output "Time difference is: $diff"
$diff
#to see minutes only
$diff.Minutes
#or seconds
$diff.Seconds
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach? That's especially important here with three other answers, some of which have been validated by the community.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete answer:

```ps1
$Date = Get-Date
$Files = gci "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\command.txt"
ForEach ($File in $Files){
    $FileDate = $File.LastWriteTime
}
$DURATION=$Date-$FileDate
Write-Host "$($DURATION.TotalMinutes)"
```

Comment: Partially based on a comment from @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command to get just TotalMinutes

```
$mins = $DURATION.TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file exists, here's a one-liner:

```
((Get-Date) - (Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\command.txt').LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes
```

You can either let it echo to the screen as is, or you can assign it to a variable if you want to retain it.